# Access to Mysql via ssh (Tunneling is not permitted )

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, ssh

When I want to access a Mysql server which only lets local accesses, first I need to SSH to that server and then run "mysql" command. However I want to run it by one command.

When I execute this command terminal stops and the cursor gets frozen after 5 or 10 seconds.

```
ssh arash@10.0.3.1 "/usr/bin/mysql -u db_username -pdfdasdfCASDF -D db_12dgj
```

Does anyone know which part is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure you got a pty for readline. Use the `-t` option of `ssh`.

```
 ssh -t -t user@server '/usr/bin/mysql -u{mysqlUser} -p{mysqlPassword} {mysqlDB} -e "select * from table"'
```

man ssh(1):

```
     -t      Force pseudo-tty allocation.  This can be used to execute arbi-
             trary screen-based programs on a remote machine, which can be
             very useful, e.g., when implementing menu services.  Multiple -t
             options force tty allocation, even if ssh has no local tty.
```

Comment: Wow you are perfect. I think only one -t is enough. I will rate this as soon as I become regular member. Thank you very much

Comment: I see so that's why you used two -t?

Comment: I guess you are executing it from other script, in that case you need two `-t`.    It never hurt to have more `-t`s.

Comment: Actually I ran it as an alias and one -t was enough but it is good to keep in mind. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Does your MySQL User have enough privilege to do that ?

Does your MySQL User have distant access to connect remotely and do operations on this database ?

In short, have you tested the classical way first before going further, e.g.

- first connect,
- second enter your mysql command
- third verify that it works.

Without tunneling:

```
ssh user@server '/usr/bin/mysql -u{mysqlUser} -p{mysqlPassword} {mysqlDB} -e "select * from table"'
```

You can escape your commands with the `-e` switch, the default escape char is `~`.

If it is not working, then I suggest you look at [these thread](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/3489) on dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Yes I can ssh and the I can run this command without any problem.
/usr/bin/mysql -u db_username -pdfdasdfCASDF -D db_12dgj

Comment: So the suggested answer should work, isn't it?

Comment: yes the answer by J-16 SDiZ works perfectly. Thanks for your contribution.